# Accessing other windows in Air

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

Is there a way to access other active windows in AIR?

I want to make an AIR app that look into the active application text and look for a specific pattern and make a transparent window into that text position to create a button.
Its a bit like the skype plug-in in Mozilla ... It replaces the telephone number with a button to launch skype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to implement what you're looking for in AIR. It doesn't have access to other application windows.